# copy three Arrays to 2 dim Array in C

Tags: c, arrays, copy

I want to copy three 1dim arrays to an 2dim array(matrix).

```
double ary2A[4] = { 0.1, 1.1, 2.1, 3.1 };
double ary2B[4] = { 0.2, 1.2, 2.2, 3.2 };
double ary2C[4] = { 0.3, 1.3, 2.3, 3.3 };

double ary1[3][4];
```

So, now I want to copy ary2A, ary2B, ary2C in ary1. How can I do this with Pointern ??

My first step was:

```
(*ary1)[4] = *ary2A;
```

But this is wrong, because I said that the address from first block of ary1 is the value 0.1.. 
And if I say

```
(*ary1)[4] = ary2A;
```

I became an Error: "assigning to 'double' from incompatible type 'double[4]'"

How can I solve this problem?? I want to check the principle..

Answer (score 2):

<s>`ary1[0] = ary2A;` will store `ary2A` at index `0` of `ary1`.</s>
Do not compile

<s>`ary1[1] = ary2B;` will store `ary2B` at index `1` of `ary1`.</s>
Do not compile

etc.

Two issues in your code :

- You are storing an array of double into a double
- You are indexing the index `4` into an array of size `4`, you are out of bounds.

If you want to create a real copy of the array, you need to perform a memory copy. You could do :

```
memcpy(ary1[0], ary2A, sizeof(double) * 4);
```

This will copy the bytes of 4 `double`s from `ary2A` into `ary1[0]`.

```
memcpy(ary1[1], ary2B, sizeof(double) * 4);
```

This will copy the bytes of 4 `double`s from `ary2B` into `ary1[1]`.

etc ...

Comment: Ok, and how can I solve this Problem? Is there any solution, to solve this with Pointern and Adress??

Comment: Actually if you want to use the `=`, you will share the memory between arrays. This means that if you modify one, you will modify the other. Is that what yo want ? The mempy solution provides you a way to not share data between arrays. It depends on what you want to do with your arrays of data.

Comment: No, you cannot use `=` with arrays, period. There is no "memory sharing" whatsoever.

Comment: @Alrick you're mistaken. You cannot write `arr[0] = A` given the definitions, period. Or you can, but it doesn't compile.

Comment: @AnttiHaapala ok it work only with pointers, not with arrays, you are right. Is it because array declared this way are allocated on the stack  when function is called ?